# Finding probability of a mixed type random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let X be a random variable of the mixed type with the CDF

$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$x<-1$} \\
\frac{x+2}{3}, & \text{$-1 \leq x <1$} \\
1, & \text{$1 \leq x$}
\end{cases}$

Determine the probabilities for P($X <0$).

> Clueless about the algorithm. What separates mixed types from continuous and discrete type? I want some references to do this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed type means that $X$ is continuous, but with discrete probabilities as well. In general, for a continuous random variable $X$, it follows that $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$. In this case, notice that $P(X=-1)=P(X\leq -1)-P(X<-1)=F(-1)-\lim_{x\to -1^-}F(x)=\frac{1}{3}-0=\frac{1}{3}$.

Note that the other "jump" at $1$ works at as follows. $P(X=1)=P(X\leq 1)-P(X<1)=F(1)-\lim_{x\to 1^-}F(x)=1-1=0$ so the only nonzero probability at a single point occurs when $x=-1$.

$X$ is also not discrete because take any $x$ in the interval $[-1,1)$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, $P([x,x+\epsilon])=F(x+\epsilon)-F(x)>0$.